# Vue js how to auto select checkbox based on database value with laravel

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, laravel, vue.js

Im new to frontend so its a bit difficult for me to tell but here is my problem. I have this `schedules` menu or table and in the table itself it has a `violation` and `remarks`. This seems hard to explain to me what I want but I will try. I got a `schedules` table and it has a relation to `checkers` and the checkers has a relation to `remarks` table. Remarks table got a static values in the database like `At room`, `Present`  and ect.. My question is how I can i loop the remarks values in the vue component and checking the remarks that is in the database. Here are my pictures.

My Component
[image]

So basically the remarks that I got is correct but I want to show the other remarks in the database without check and if i got two remarks, two checkbox will be checked. But if i have two remarks in DB it doubles the display.

Here is my Database
[image]

The `remarks_id` is number 9 and the value of that is `at lecture room` which is correct.

I cant write my query because it is too long and i know it will difficult for you to understand but incase you want here it is

```
 //schedule_id
        $scid = $request->id;
        $round = \DB::table('rounds')
        ->select('rounds.*','checkers.*','remarks.*','violations.*')
        ->join('checkers','checkers.id','=','rounds.checker_id')
        ->join('checker_details','rounds.id','=','checker_details.round_id')
        ->join('remarks','remarks.id','=','rounds.remarks_id')
        ->join('violations','violations.id','=','checker_details.violation_id')
        ->where('checkers.schedule_id',$scid)
        ->where('rounds.round_no','=',1)
        ->distinct('rounds.remarks_id')
        ->get();
        return response()->json($round);
```

The included tables in the query
[image]

Code snippet for the component shown

```
 <div class="row" v-for="detail in details" :key="detail.id">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="box box-success">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Violations</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-check-input" checked="checked" 
type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                                {{detail.violation_details}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="box box-success">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Remarks</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-check-input" checked="checked" 
type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                                {{detail.remarks_desc}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I hope you understand my problem. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the docs about how to work with checkboxes https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox . You should modify your checkboxes to something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="checked">
```

Comment: @Vince , I have made mistake. Wait until I fix it.

Comment: can we chat sir?

Comment: @Vince, yes, we can.

Comment: do you have a skype or something to chat unto?

Comment: We can do it in vuejs chat or in slack chat.

Comment: ok we do in vuejs chat or slack is also ok. invite me in slack

Comment: whats your email?

Comment: just join here sir https://join.slack.com/t/vue-vmr4432/shared_invite/enQtOTAzNDc1MzMyNDAxLTRmODE2MTE3NDJkZGRiMjgwMzBiZjcxOTM2NTBiZTVhOGMxYjcyY2MwYzhjY2ExOGIyN2ZhMDdmY2E4ZjY5MjY

Comment: if someone wants to help just join us in slack thanks :)